# RTL8188CU USB Network Adaptor on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, 13.04

I have an RTL8188CU USB Network Adaptor. On Ubuntu 12.10 I had to download RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105 because the built-in rtl8192cu driver did not work on the 64bit system (Tested fine on 32bit). Now I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and of cause the switch from kernel 3.4 to 3.8 broke the compatibility with the driver source. And (Like I suspected), the 64bit issue with rtl8192cu has still not been resolved. Since Realtek has not yet provided a new driver source, I have no working network on my computer (I use USB Tethering from my mobile at the moment). I tried downloading the Windows driver and set it up with ndiswrapper, but as soon as I activate the ndiswrapper module while having that driver installed, I get a kernel panic.

Since I cannot be the only one using this USB Adaptor, I wanted to see if someone else might have found a solution to get something working? Someone might even have a solution as to why the built-in 64bit driver does not work?

Comment: After searching a bit more, I found a thread where someone said that the issue with rtl8192cu had been resolved in kernel 3.8.6, so I tried compiling this version and even 3.8.10 as well, but still no luck.

Comment: For other with the same issue, the kernel devs are working on the issue but for now, people with newer kernels can use this: [link](https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/). If you don't have a debian based system, just extract the package and build the dkms yourself.

Comment: Worked great.  I think at this point you can answer (and accept) your own question.  This helped at least one other person (me) so I think it would be great to have an accepted answer show up in the searches.

Answer (score 5):

FIXED!! - Well, PATCHED!

https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/

After 24 hours of pulling my hair out over the same problem, I found this link somewhere in a response to the topic. Bless this soul for patching Realtek's drivers to work on current kernels 3.8.x & 3.9.x - Its a DEB package, so no compiling issues, you may need to install specially if your system is not dpkg-based.

...TELL THE WORLD! No more high blood pressure from (this) device driver issue!