# 14.04:Driver for Realtek 8188CU

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

How can I install driver for Realtek 8188CU Wifi USB adapter?

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364972/realtek-8188cus-doesnt-work) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286079/rtl8188cu-usb-network-adaptor-on-ubuntu-13-04)

But didn't worked nothing.

Is there a solution for that?

```
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:444:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_signal;
   ^
   /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:446:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    entry = create_proc_read_entry("ampdu_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
    ^
  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:452:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   entry->write_proc = proc_set_ampdu_enable;
   ^
   /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:454:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    entry = create_proc_read_entry("rssi_disp", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
    ^
 /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:460:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    entry->write_proc = proc_set_rssi_disp;
   ^
  cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
  make[1]: ** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Erro 1
  make: ** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build] Erro 2
   make: Saindo do diretório `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic'
```

Comment: What is the result of `lsusb`

Comment: vitor@vitor-pc:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 064e:f203 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:1000 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: And who told you that you had a Realtek 8188CU? I see a Ralink.

Comment: humm I know that USB wifi is this model http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-694168355-adaptador-wireless-usb-wifi-150mbps-sem-fio-lan-bgn-antena-_JM#redirectedFromParent

Comment: Is a Ralink Rt5370

Comment: See chili555's answer for [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation)

Comment: but is a other model? can be used for?

Comment: Upvote chili555's answer if it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big, big update.**

To me it seems you are missing out on a couple of basic things:

- A driver is a software module that needs to match **both**, your actual kernel version **and** your actual make and model of your device. So, if you have a Ralink RT5370, as your lsusb log indicates, you should use the Ralink driver indeed. The Realtek driver will not help you in any way with this.
- To find out what driver you need you can:

  1. look at the device itself. Most of the time you'll find a very good identification printed on it. Google is your friend.
  2. use the tools in your computer like `lsusb`, `lsmod` or `lspci`. Google for the device ID's.

If you build your driver from source, and it does **not** build with your actual kernel version, try building with another kernel version. With linux it is really easy to switch kernel versions at boot. If you need help to install an older kernel version, follow [this post to Install older kernel version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303081/install-older-kernel-version).

**if you positively identified that you have a Ralink RT5370**

You probably should follow the instructions from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1949996), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/692229/install-driver-for-rt5370-on-ubuntu) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99373/building-driver-for-ralink-rt5370-usb-wifi-wlan-dongle).

**if (and only if) you have a RealTek 8188:**

Try [this from google code](https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/downloads/list). It's patched driver from realtek.

But you have to blacklist the native drivers: put a file in to /etc/modprobe.d/ with the following in it:

```
# Blacklist native RealTek 8188CUs drivers
blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist rtl8192c_common
blacklist rtlwifi
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan Willi, It return me a error of kernel.

Comment: @VitorMazuco This is a wrong version for your kernel. Try my answer. It will build.

Comment: humm I'm install kernel 4.2 it will fix it?

Comment: The link in this answer is to an old driver. It will not build for new kernels. I gave you commands that will install a driver that will build for your kernel.

Comment: Ok, I have installed new kernel 4.2 and removed the old.

Comment: I tried to install in a new kernel, but it continue with error

Comment: Done.
Unpacking rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms (1.6) over (1.6) ...
Configurando rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms (1.6) ...
Loading new rtl8192cu-tjp-1.6 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.2.0-040200-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.2.0-040200-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.2.0-040200-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-040200-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/make.log for more information.